# Constructing a no-query secure MAC II

Tags: encryption, mac

I'm trying to construct a no-query-secure MAC $II=(Gen,Mac,Vrfy)$ without using any cryptographic primitives such as PRF, PRG, has function, etc.

**My-attempt**:

I learned that a message authentication code (MAC) is no-query-secure if in the security game the adversary is not allowed to query for any MAC.

I tried to get the Gen, Mac, and Vrfy as follows

Gen$(1^n):$ Sample $k←\{0,1\}^n$ and output $k$.

Mac$_k(m):$ where $m∈\{0,1\}^n:$ and Output $t$

Vrfy$_k(m,t):$ Output 1 if and only if $?$

I couldn't figure it out what Mac will output i.e. $t=?$ and Vrfy will output?

Comment: Hint: Somehow using the output of Gen might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Suggested plan: Write down a detailed definition of a no-query secure MAC (that's half the work; add it to the question or be off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). It requires that $\text{Mac}_k(m)$ computes $t$ of what nature? For $\text{Vrfy}$, stick to $t=\text{Mac}_k(m)$. Now for $\text{Mac}_k$: try $t$ being a constant, then each input of that algorithm (which are?) that has the right characteristics. Is the resulting construction no-query secure, and why exactly? Iterate with the simplest you think that was not tried yet until something matches the definition.